# How to listen to messages which are sent to ActorSystem (Akka 2.0)

Tags: java, akka

I have a code, where I create an Actor from AkkaSystem.

```
return system.actorOf(Props.apply(new Creator<Actor>()
....
```

Inside the child actor I call

```
context().parent().tell(new DeathByError());
context().stop(self());
```

is there a way to know from the parent (ActorSystem object) to know that child sent `DeathByError` message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant "what" child sent the message, Micheal Rose's answer is correct.

If you simply want to receive it, add a handler for it in the parents receive method.

Note that if you "watch" an actor from another actor, the latter is notified when the former dies, without need for you to explicitly sending a message ( http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Actor_Lifecycle )

Answer (score 1):

When you are handling the message you can call `getSender()` which should return the `ActorRef` of the one who sent the message.